# Как работает выражение this.$() в jquery?

Tags: jquery, javascript

Не давно в одном исходнике встретил след. выражение  this.$().prop('someProp') Собственно я не понимаю конструкции .$() т.к. раньше такого не встречал. Смею предположить, что это тоже самое что и $(this), но все же спрошу как это работает? Если не затруднит дайте пожалуйста ссылку на документацию.
Заранее благодарю.

Answer (score 1):

this.$() — обычно это означет сделать выборку (jQuery.fn.find) в контексте компонента, либо вернуть ссылку на контекст, например:

```
function MyComponent(el, options){
    this.$el = $(el);
    this.options = options;
}

MyComponent.prototptye = {
    $: function (selector){
        return selector ? this.$el.find(selector) : this.$el;
    },

    render: function (){
        this.$().html('....');
        this.$('.js-label').on('click', ...);
    }
};
```

P.S. http://backbonejs.org/docs/backbone.html#section-122 или https://github.com/RubaXa/Pilot/blob/master/Pilot.js#L1169

Comment: а вот откуда взялся backbone ?

Comment: "Не давно в одном исходнике встретил след. выражение this.$().prop('someProp')"

Backbone просто пример такого рода функций, где именно встретил z_coder такую конструкцию я не знаю. Например в  [Ember][1] можно писать именно так.

[1]: https://github.com/emberjs/ember.js/blob/v1.2.0/packages/ember-views/lib/views/view.js#L1408

Comment: да, но тогда надо говорить, что это backbone/ember а не просто пример приводить, т.к. к jQuery это отношения не имеет.

Comment: Человек сказал, что не понимает и хочет узнать, что это может значить. К jQuery это имеет прямое отношение, есть негласное правило, что методы или перменные начинающиеся c **$** возвращают jQuery коллекцию, а метод this.$ ищет внутри контекста компонента.

Comment: вот я прочитав ваш ответ подумал "чего за ересь, неужели я не знаю о том что jQuery встраивает свой прототип в Object ?" А кто-то не подумает и попытается это использовать в хэндлерах событий и тд.

Comment: Мне кажется вы совсем не поняли мой ответ, а жаль, но это больше моя вина. На этом и закончу.

Comment: Я понял ваш ответ, он неверный.

Comment: @eicto, вы совершенно не поняли мой ответ, я хотел донести, что есть негласное правило, если названия переменной или метода начинаются с доллора, то это означет, что такой метод вернет jQuery коллекцию. Так что если в коде встретили `this.$()` или `this.$('.foo')` можно быть уверенным, что такой метод вернет jQuery коллекцию на родительский контейнер, либо сделает выборку в нём.

Comment: @RubaXa, ваше негласное правило работает для одного-двух конкретных реализаций конкретных библиотек(?). в остальных случаях - это какой-то велосипед с дополнительными зависимостями, ни под какие правила не подпадающий. кто-то как-то изменил чей-то прототип, так вот чтоб понять что там вернется надо смотреть api этого конкретного чего-то. у jquery на знак $ нету монополии, @eicto верно вспомнил про mootools и вообще jQuery.noConflict...

Comment: И извиняюсь, мне все-таки следовало бы упомянуть ember и привести разбираемый мною код что бы быть более конкретным. Обсуждаемую конструкцию я нашел здесь: https://github.com/emberjs/ember.js/blob/v1.2.0/packages/ember-handlebars/lib/controls/checkbox.js#L11

Answer (score 1):

в контексте jQuery, если this!==window - ничего (если конечно где-то не определено дополнительно в плагине например). ибо

```
jQuery(function($){
    console.log('$.fn.$',$.fn.$); //$.fn.$ undefined 
    $('button').click(function() {
     console.log(this,this.$); // <button>clickme</button>  undefined
    });
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/oceog/uHz7P/

Comment: @RubaXa **негласных правил не существует**, вспомним хотя-бы mootools. То что вы называете правилами является **традицией**. Отличие традиции от правила в том, что традиция существует в сознании определенной группы людей, она может меняться или быть необязательной, скажем, если я использую знак доллара в совершенно не относящейся к jQuery, и опишу это в документации или соглашении о коде, то я никого не введу в заблуждение, в  отличии от вашего ответа. С другой стороны если я использую $ и не опишу этого, я введу пользователя либы в заблуждение.